# Crear recurso para una imagen + tooltip que utilizare bastantes veces en el entorno grafico

Tags: c#, xaml, tooltip

Tengo el siguiente código;

```
           <Image Source="C:\Users\Casa PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PcS7\PcS7\Icons\info.png" Height="22" Margin="0,0,0,2">
                         <Image.ToolTip>
                             <StackPanel>
                                 <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,5">Ruta de archivo...</TextBlock>
                                 <TextBlock Text="El archivo se guardará en el siguiente directorio;"/>
                                 <TextBlock></TextBlock>
                                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ruta, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                 <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Margin="0,8" />
                                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                     <Image Source="C:\Users\Casa PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PcS7\PcS7\Icons\info.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                                     <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontStyle="Italic">Presione F1 para mas información</TextBlock>
                                 </StackPanel>
                             </StackPanel>
                         </Image.ToolTip>
           </Image>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se trata de una imagen que levanta un `tootltip` cuando pasas el ratón por encima y que te informa del estado de ciertas partes del programa, la idea es poder tener una plantilla de ese código y poder utilizarla en muchas partes de este sin tener que repetir continuamente todo el código una y otra vez.
Tengo entendido que hay posibilidad de utilizar recursos que hacen lo que busco, pero no logro entenderlos bien del todo y he preferido preguntarlo en el foro y que sea alguien con mas experiencia en `XAML` quien me pueda orientar mejor.

Utilizando un `UserControl` casi consigo lo que busco pero si intento enlazar el valor de un `String` mediante un `Binding` obtengo el siguiente error;

[image: Error VS]

En cambio si que puedo introducir un texto directamente como en la anterior propiedad, "Linea1", por ejemplo.
¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias

Comment: No es suficiento como meterlo en un control de usuario?

Comment: Preferiría hacerlo con un recurso para familiarizarme con el, además, quería utilizarlo solamente en el xaml, ¿Sería posible?

Comment: ehh.. si... es posible...